# Is mootools.js important for jquery lightbox in joomla

Tags: jquery, lightbox

My question is that Is mootools.js file of joomla1.5 package, important for jquery lightbox file for zooming effetc , because that effect is not working in my site... 
Please do reply as soon as possible..

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just put the file there and see if it works, rather than asking a question about it?

Answer (score 0):

jquery and mootools are two javascript framework you can check comparison here http://jqueryvsmootools.com/. Regarding your question , as they are  different js framework so they can be conflict with each other if proper steps is not taken. You better give us a link it will be easier for us to give you a solution.